# Beamer bibliography in two columns on multiple frames?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, columns

Is it possible to put a bibliography in beamer presentation, in two columns spanning via several frames?

I have

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{mybib}
\end{frame}
```

And that will split the references on multiple slides, which is nice, but still there are too many slides created just for references. So I tried with `multicol` package, but I only get some of the references, and only on one slide (I kept the `allowframebreaks` on the frame). So that's kinda a bust :\

I've searched all over but no luck.

I'd give a mwe, but I'd need to give a .bib file, dunno how that can help...

Comment: `beamer` advocates and structures itself towards an opinionated (though resonates quite well with me) and disciplined way of creating presentations. Hence it also modifies tables, graphics, bibliographies towards that mindset. What you are trying to do is considered to be a very bad practice from the viewpoint of the creator of `beamer` hence the difficulty. I would consider creating your bib slides externally and collate to your document later if this is really really needed.

Comment: So I should have like 5 slides of references in my presentation? :\ That seems so redundant to me. Especially if it's the seminar paper that contains all the details I'm giving speech about.

Comment: The redundancy is having all your references in the presentation. Consider having handouts which are supported by the `beamer` that includes all the details in the article mode. The manual has a long chapter about different options of supplementary material.

Comment: @dingo_d No, you should have only 5 most important references in the presentation. During a talk, noone can read 30 references, and if you publish the slides on web, you might consider publish a manuscript as well, and there mention all the references in the standard way.

Comment: Oh, right... You do have a point. Is there any reference how to make short list of my original bibliography, or do I simply make a new one with most important stuff in it?
Thanks for all the suggestions :)

Comment: I for one would still love to see a real answer here. The author of beamer worked under very specific circumstances that do not apply to all situations. Yes, it is bad form to show an audience too many references, but sometimes one is *required* to have a single document that contains both the primary material and a full citation list, even if the latter is not usually shown to the audience during the presentation proper. Unlike Nature papers, slide shows as scientific media are sometimes best kept as a *single* document.

Comment: One of my favorite comments on beamer which I found in a different place is: "As shown multiple times in the manual the author likes to indicate his personal opinion with quite strong wording. This quote is one such occasion. It is rather useless to argue about that and especially use them in technical discussions such as this one. There are various ways to make use of the combination of the two respective features with very good reasons that neither the author of any latex package nor we the stackexchange community are entitled to judge."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this:

```
\section*{Références}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\frametitle{\insertsection} \usebeamertemplate{frametitle}]
\bibliography{Biblio.bib}
\bibliographystyle{auteurfr}
\end{multicols}
```

By this way you can have bibliography in two columns on multiple frames.
In the first frame, the frametitle beamer template appear with the name of the section.