# beamer reference list

Tags: beamer, biblatex, vertical-alignment

I am using Beamer with `biblatex`.

When I used the code below, it produced a bibliography which has three slides. But the references in the last slide are in the center rather than top. So the first two slides look good, but the last reference slide is centered.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
 \end{frame}
```

I tried the following, but it made it worse..

```
 \begin{frame}[t][allowframebreaks]
```

Do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thanks @Claudio Fiandrino, my question is actually similar to the [one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95464/beamer-bibliography-in-two-columns-on-multiple-frames?rq=1), but this one was not fixed. Are you using different text editor includes {}button?

Comment: Absolutely no. :) You can find the `{}` button above in the bar above the text box when you ask/answer a question.

Comment: You are right to smile:) I am newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

You should write `\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]`:

[image: Sample output]

Sample of final page from:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xampl.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \nocite{*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it works! and seems to be very easy solution.